# how to get data from a sub query and also know if sub query is empty or not?

Tags: sql

I have three tables

T1 has columns:

```
Number, ID
```

T2 has columns:

```
Number, ID
```

T3 has columns:

```
Number, Name
```

I know an ID value: *MYID*.

I want to select every row from T3 where the *Number* is equal to any *Number* in T2 or T1 where with *ID* equal to the *MYID*. Also I want to know all the *Number*s that are either in T1 or T2 that have a corresponding *ID* equal to *MYID* -- (the subquery below).

I have written this query:

```
SELECT * FROM T3 where T3.Number in 
(SELECT T2.NUMBER FROM T2 where T2.ID=MYID
 union 
 SELECT T1.NUMBER FROM T1 where T1.ID=MYID)
```

With this query some *Number*s present in the subquery are not known if they are not present in T3. Now should I split into two queries or is there a way to get all that information in one query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is MYID and where is it coming from? Is it a variable or a hardcoded value ?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags

Comment: @M.Ali It is a harcoded value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing this as:

```
SELECT T3.*,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T2 WHERE T2.ID = MYID AND T2.NUMBER = T3.NUMBER)
             THEN 1
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T1 WHERE T1.ID = MYID AND T1.NUMBER = T1.NUMBER)
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END) as flag
FROM T3;
```

This is better than the `UNION` form because the subqueries can take advantage of indexes on `T2` and `T1`.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer try this: (im guessing that you know what MYID is, I don't)

```
WITH t
AS (SELECT
    T2.number
FROM T2
WHERE T2.ID = MYID
UNION
SELECT
    T1.number
FROM T1
WHERE T1.ID = MYID)


SELECT
*
,CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT
                *
            FROM t
            WHERE t.number = T3.number) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS ExistsInOtherSets
FROM T3
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that MYID is a hard coded value; something like this should do the trick ....

```
SELECT * FROM T3 
where EXISTS (SELECT 1                       
              FROM T2 
              where T2.NUMBER = T3.Number
                AND T2.ID = MYID) 
OR    EXISTS (SELECT 1                       
              FROM T1 
              where T1.NUMBER = T3.Number
                AND T1.ID = MYID)
```